# Model not generating error for drop down list for default value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model

```
  C# code 
 public class customer
   {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; } 
   }
```

ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(Uow.Countries.GetAll(), "Id", "Name");

```
  modelbuilder 
       modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasRequired(p => p.Country)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Customers)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.CountryId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);




      <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, "CountryId", new { @class = "control-    label" })
          <div class="controls">
         @Html.DropDownList("CountryId","select country"); 
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, null, new { @class =  "help-inline" })
        </div>
        </div>
```

**I am not getting model error while clicking save button with default value as
   "select country""**
instead i am getting error **"
The ViewData item that has the key 'CountryId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable "**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountryId` in you drop down list is `Model.CountryId`, not `ViewBag.CountryId`. Try this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CountryId,"select country");
```

I also suggest you choose different names for your collection and the property getting selected value.

Comment: above problem is solved.after changing,but when Model is in edit mode drop down list is not binding with selected value instead it is select always first drop down list item any suggestion,but in code like i wrote above it selected correct value in edit.

Comment: Is `Model.CountryId` correctly setted before being sent to your view ?

Comment: at model its not coming correct any value but while returning model object from controller to view countryId is selected correct value

Comment: ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(Uow.Countries.GetAll(), "Id", "Name", customer.CountryId);                                            It is my code for returning dropdown list from controller to view ..where customer is model. Any thing wrong passing like above countryid to view as viewbag expression

Comment: ViewBag is not really a best practice, you'd better make a view model, which contains your customer and a country list. This helps building strongly typed views.